# Are events emitted from a contract synchronously?

Tags: events

Does anyone know how events emitted from a contract?

I can't seem to find an authoritative answer while googling and I am kind of worried that they are synchronous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Events are emitted when a [transaction is mined into a block,](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3938/42) in the order they are fired.

When watching a pending transaction, this suggests that filters are only notified of all events when the transaction is completed, but the order of events is preserved.

> [When [events] are called](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events) they cause the arguments to be stored in the transaction’s log - a
>   special data structure in the blockchain. These logs are associated
>   with the address of the contract and will be incorporated into the
>   blockchain...

Comment: Ok, that clarifies some things. But what happens to the execution of a miner if its transaction log runs out of disk or takes a really long time to complete? Will this miner effectively block the execution for the entire network?

Comment: [Each log costs gas and ultimately limited by the block gas limit](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1686/42) so they are no problem for miners to handle.

Comment: @Daniel If a miner runs out of disk, it won't successfully mine the block, so some other node will.