# What are the benefits of using events over dedicated indexed variable?

Tags: contract-design, gas, events, logs

Good day.

I'm trying to grasp the concept of events in the EVM and I just can't understand what is the incentive of using events. Why not just use a dedicated public index that will hold information? Isn't the event data just stored on the block chain like a regular variable?

As always, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Events are the built-in way for something external, such as a user interface, to be notified of something from the blockchain.  When an event is emitted, the watchers of that event are notified.  No notifications happen when a contract variable is updated.
2. Events are [stored differently](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/where-do-contract-event-logs-get-stored-in-the-ethereum-architecture) and are [much cheaper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/ethereum-event-log-maximum-size) than using contract storage.  [Contracts cannot access logs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/can-a-contract-listen-to-events-of-another-contract) directly.

Events are not in the EVM (you won't find them in the [Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper)); events in Solidity and Serpent are wrappers around the LOG opcode in the EVM.