# What's cheaper — contract storage | log data | transaction input?

Tags: gas, storage

I want to collect user data and store it on the blockchain. Let's say I need to store usernames. Is the cost of storing 1 byte on the blockchain different for contract storage/log data/transaction input?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Contract storage is the most expensive at [generally 20,000 gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/is-the-cost-of-updating-storage-different-than-the-cost-of-adding-to-storage) for each 32 bytes (which is 1 storage slot).

Logs cost 375 gas for a LOG operation. 375 gas for each topic. 8 gas for each byte of a LOG operation's data.  See [Ethereum event log maximum size](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/ethereum-event-log-maximum-size) for more information.

Transaction input costs 4 gas for a zero byte, and 68 gas for a non-zero byte.

Important consideration: **Does the data need to be accessible directly by contracts?**  If so, contract storage is the only option: contracts [can't directly access logs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/can-a-contract-listen-to-events-of-another-contract) or other transactions.