# Regarding Event Generation Cost

Tags: events

Lets say events are invoked from all the methods of a contract. Each event is storing some data. The methods where only computation or data fetching logic is applied will it cost ether if any event is generated from these kind of methods?

Comment: Yes, events store data and will always cost ether. Examples:
http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/ethereum-event-log-maximum-size

Comment: Events that only fetch and do logic may be marked "constant" in which case the event mission won't work as might be expected.

Comment: Well the methods could be only constant when there is no storage operation. If it is generating an event then i believe it cannot be constant. That means as a convention we should not apply any event in those kind of methods.